# not able to route exact data in navigation.setOptions

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Value of 'tans' is not routed properly in navigation.setOptions, how can I route 'tans' value in next screen in navigation options?

```
    React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
            navigation.setOptions({
                headerRight: () => (
                    <View style={{ ...styles.info, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Summary',
                            { tans: tans, })}>
                            <Text style={{
                                fontSize: 16, fontFamily: "OpenSans-Bold",
                                color: '#e74645', margin: 20
                            }}>Submit</Text>
                        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                    </View>
                ),
                headerLeft: () => { return null; }
            });
        }, [navigation]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expecting the variable "tans" to change, you need to add it to dependency like below.

```
React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerRight: () => (
                <View style={{ ...styles.info, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Summary',
                        { tans: tans, })}>
                        <Text style={{
                            fontSize: 16, fontFamily: "OpenSans-Bold",
                            color: '#e74645', margin: 20
                        }}>Submit</Text>
                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                </View>
            ),
            headerLeft: () => { return null; }
        });
    }, [navigation, tans]);  // <----- this line
```